# WPF: Uninitialized Fill property breaks IsMouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, ismouseover

I have this XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TTT_01.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="146" Canvas.Top="110" Height="100" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" Width="200" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

and this is the C# code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{      
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rectangle1.IsMouseOver)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click!");
        }
    }
}
```

What I see is a white rectangle. When I click into the rectangle I expect the message box to pop up. This doesn't happen though, unless I initialize the `Fill` property of the rectangle either in XAML or in the MainWindow constructor. Without `Fill` being initialized `rectangle1.IsMouseOver` remains `false` even though I click into the rectangle.

What does `Fill` have to do with `IsMouseOver`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fill is part of what specifies the hit test area of your controls. In WPF controls generally do a pixel-perfect hit test, not a rectangular one. For example, if you put an `<Ellipse/>` in you XAML, clicking outside of the circumference, but inside the bounding rectangle won't generate a MouseDown event in the Ellipse (this one is kind of obvious though). In the same way not specifying a Fill for a Shape means that the inside of the shape simply doesn't exist - it hit tests negatively and lets clicks fall through. In other words, shapes without a Fill only constitute of their outline for purposes of hit testing.

If you want to have a border-only transparent rectangle (or any other `Shape`) that still hit tests on the inside, then specify `Fill="Transparent"`.

This is true not only for shapes, but also for containers like `Grid` and `Border` - if you don't specify a `Background`, then their empty area doesn't register in hit testing.

Comment: The MSDN article [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) has all the details.